# While loop, find value closest to zero

Tags: swift, while-loop

I am trying to find the rate that makes IRDPenaltyCalculation equal to 0. I can get this value using a UISlider. But I want to calculate the value so that I can set the UISlider min value. The below code gives the wrong rate and does not run until IRDPenaltyCalculation equals 0. I feel like I am overlooking a simple step.

```
var IRDPenaltyCalculation = IRDPenalty(IRDComparisonRate: Double(comparisonRate / 100), mtgBalance: mortgageBalance, mthsToMaturity: Double(monthsToMaturity), discount: Double(mortgageRateDiscount), currentRate: rate)

while IRDPenaltyCalculation > 0 {
    rate -= 0.01

    print("Rate: \(rate)")

    IRDPenaltyCalculation = IRDPenalty(IRDComparisonRate: Double(comparisonRate / 100), mtgBalance: mortgageBalance, mthsToMaturity: Double(monthsToMaturity), discount: Double(mortgageRateDiscount), currentRate: rate)

    print("IRD: \(IRDPenaltyCalculation)")
    rateLabel.text =  String(IRDPenaltyCalculation)

}
```

Comment: By Swift's convention, variables should use `lowerCamelCase`. `UpperCamelCase` should only be used for type names.

Comment: This seems sketchy. Are you sure there isn't a closed form mathematical solution to this? That would be faster, simpler and more precise.

Comment: The label's text will not update until after the loop completes. There's no point setting it on every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
while IRDPenalty(IRDComparisonRate: Double(comparisonRate / 100), mtgBalance: mortgageBalance, mthsToMaturity: Double(monthsToMaturity), discount: Double(mortgageRateDiscount), currentRate: rate) > 0 {
    rate -= 0.01
}
print("Rate: \(rate)")

var IRDPenaltyCalculation = IRDPenalty(IRDComparisonRate: Double(comparisonRate / 100), mtgBalance: mortgageBalance, mthsToMaturity: Double(monthsToMaturity), discount: Double(mortgageRateDiscount), currentRate: rate)

print("IRD: \(IRDPenaltyCalculation)")
rateLabel.text =  String(IRDPenaltyCalculation)
```